# How to rollback to a specific change set with Liquibase Command Line

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, liquibase

I have a two changeLog files (changeLog-1.0.1.xml, changeLog-2.0.1.xml).
Each changeLog file contains two changeSets (changeSet-1, changeSet-1)
Both are being executed at app deploy time.

This is how I specify the changeSets:

```
<changeSet id="changeSet-1" author="someUser" labels="labelOne">
    <createTable tableName="testTable" schemaName="public">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <rollback>
        <dropTable tableName="testTable"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

I want to rollback the second changeLog file (changeLog2.xml) from command line.

I tried a lot of ways, but did not succeed.

```
java -jar C:\..\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar update rollback changeSet-1 --changeLogFile="changeLog-1.0.1.xml"
```

when being in the same dir as changeLog file

update: I managed to successfully call update from command line

```
    java -jar C:\Users\someUser\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar 
--changeLogFile=changeLog.xml 
--labels=labelOne 
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app2db 
--classpath=C:/postgresql-42.1.4.jar 
--username=app2user 
--password=password 
update
```

and for rollback

```
    java -jar C:\Users\someUser\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar 
--changeLogFile=changeLog.xml 
--labels=labelOne 
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app2db 
--classpath=C:/postgresql-42.1.4.jar 
--username=app2user 
--password=password 
rollback
```

the call crashes with

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: rollback requires a rollback tag
```

Comment: You can also rollback by date or even by number of changesets [look here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to create a tag first

```
java -jar C:\path\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar  
--changeLogFile=changeLog.xml
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app2db
--classpath=C:/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
--username=app2user
--password=password
tag exampletag
```

then do the rollback to that specific tag

```
java -jar C:\path\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar
--changeLogFile=changeLog.xml
--labels=labelOne
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app2db
--classpath=C:/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
--username=app2user
--password=password
rollback exampletag
```